# In ORACLE get values from 01-01-YYYY to 12-31-YYYY previous year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In ORACLE I am trying to get values from `PS_EMP_REVIEW_GOAL` with a `REVIEW_DT` between **01-01-YYYY** and **12-31-YYYY** from last year.

I get the following error msg:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

*Cause:

*Action:

```
SELECT
ERG.REVIEW_DT,
ERG.CAREER_GOAL
from PS_EMP_REVIEW_GOAL  ERG, PS_PERSONNEL P
where ERG.EMPLID = P.EMPLID
and ERG.REVIEW_DT = (Select max(ERG1.REVIEW_DT) from PS_EMP_REVIEW_GOAL  ERG1
where ERG1.EMPLID = ERG.EMPLID
and ERG1.REVIEW_DT BETWEEN to_date('01-01-' || trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'))-1
                       AND to_date('12-31-' || trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'))-1 
);
```

Comment: You should never use `to_date()` without a format mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')` will return whole date, which you then try to concatenate with day and month:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') FROM dual;
```

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')
---------------------
01-01-2013
```

What you should do instead is `EXTRACT` the year from `SYSDATE` and use the date format model to convert the string into a `DATE`:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01-01-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE), 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 1 AS val
FROM dual;
```

```
VAL      
----------
31-12-2012
```

So your code should look like this:

```
SELECT
ERG.REVIEW_DT,
ERG.CAREER_GOAL
from PS_EMP_REVIEW_GOAL  ERG, PS_PERSONNEL P
where ERG.EMPLID = P.EMPLID
and ERG.REVIEW_DT = (Select max(ERG1.REVIEW_DT) from PS_EMP_REVIEW_GOAL  ERG1
where ERG1.EMPLID = ERG.EMPLID
and ERG1.REVIEW_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE), 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 1
                       AND TO_DATE('12-31-' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE), 'MM-DD-YYYY') - 1
);
```

**Edit** If you want to compare the date with the dates from the previous year, you should move the `- 1` inside the `TO_DATE` like this:

```
and ERG1.REVIEW_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 1), 'MM-DD-YYYY')
                       AND TO_DATE('12-31-' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 1), 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: +1 for also using a format mask for the `to_date()` function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I shiver each time I see conversion between date and string and v. v. without a format mask.

Comment: From an Oracle novice, thanks, when using the -1 inside TO_DATE gave me the previous years data.

Answer (score 1):

Another shorter option would be:

```
extract(year from ERG1.REVIEW_DT) = extract(year from current_date) - 1
```

**BUT**: this would **not** use an an index on `ERG1.REVIEW_DT` so it might be to slow for your purposes. IN that case Przemyslaw's answer is much better, because that expression *can* use an index on that column.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will implement the logic you're asking for

```
and ERG1.REVIEW_DT BETWEEN trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
                       AND add_months( trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 12 ) - 1
```

Given that an Oracle `DATE` always has a day and a time component, though, this will exclude rows where `review_dt` is on 12/31 but after midnight.  My guess is that you really want

```
and ERG1.REVIEW_DT >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
AND ERG1.REVIEW_DT <  add_months( trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 12 )
```